# Android Studio , startService() is creating object every time stopService() and startService() is called

Tags: android

It seems that the object created by startService() holds in memory forever till I log out or totally close the App.
As per the documentation, I read stopService() should destroy the Service object but the real-time scenario seems to be different. Every time I call stopservice() the service object stays in memory and when I start the service again with startService() a new object is getting created and both services the old and new one starts running. This keeps on increasing to 3 4 5 ... and so on as many time stopservice() and startService() is called. To confirm my tinking I define 'instenceId' (Below is the code) and on my server Upload data, I see 'instenceId's old and new ones, to elaborate I got Location event in the service and I upload data in the event to the server, so on the server, I see that many events with old new 'instenceId's. i.e old object is retained in the memory.

I know this should not happen, maybe I am doing something wrong.

```
public class AutoConnectService extends Service implements SensorEventListener,
        com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
{
String instenceId = "";

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        initializeRequisite();
        instenceId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

Ref
stackoverflow.com/questions/8019899/what-happens-if-a-android-service-is-started-multiple-times
concretepage.com/android/android-start-stop-service-from-activity-example-using-handlerthread

Comment: When your `Service` stops, are you unregistering it as a listener for all of those interfaces that it implements?

Comment: Yes I am, but unfortunately, the reregister is called in onStartCommand() so when I call startService() the old onStartCommand() also called with the one, and all old and new listeners become active and start triggering.

Comment: `Service`s are singletons, so I'm not sure that you're interpreting your observations correctly. I would also mention that `onStartCommand()` can be called multiple times for a single `Service` instance, so the UUID that you're generating there isn't really useful for tracking instances.

Comment: Services are singletons, does it mean that we define it singleton or Android treats it as singleton. because if I remove public constructor (making it private) from service class startservice() throw an exception.

Comment: The system handles that. Your `Service` shouldn't have any explicit constructors at all, unless you've implemented an `AppComponentFactory` in your app.